# jQuery and CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have written a jQuery code at http://jsfiddle.net/48k7g/5/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#pph_test').hide('slow');
});
```

I need to make it similar to this:

[image: example]

Clicking on the button will open up a new section as shown in the image example. Please also help me with the proper CSS to make it look like the example.

Comment: Please show what have you tried - HTML, CSS, jQuery

Comment: I can't see image, broken link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is to make a div at the top of that container have the css of `float:right;`. I've added extra css to make it look more similar to the image.

```
.float {
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:grey;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

And then the button would be:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#pph_test .float').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48k7g/8/

Comment: Thanks. And what would be the CSS for the button to make it similar to that in the image?

Comment: @EclecticSolutions This should include the button that is close to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/48k7g/26/

Answer (score 0):

add this into css,

```
#display{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:2px solid;
    float:right;
    height:50px;
}
```

and this is in js,

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $('#display').toggle('slow');
});
```

see live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E2HNT/)

Answer (score 0):

didn't see any new content tags in your code. did you mean like this:

```
JSFiddle eg: http://jsfiddle.net/48k7g/9/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write html like following

```
<div id="pph_test">
    <div id="new"></div>
    <h3>Welcome to QuickSchools</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Click Me"></input>
</div>
```

then in CSS

```
#new {
    background:#e5e5e5;
    height:100px; 
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    display:none;
}
```

and then jquery

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
      $('#new').toggle('slow');
  });
```

it gives similar output as you specified in your images.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

    #a { height: auto; width:700px; margin:0 auto; background:#eee; padding:10px;}
    p.click { background:#f00; height:30px; width:100px; text-align:center; line-height:30px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer;}
    #abc { background:#ccc; height:200px; width:480px; float:right; }
    span{ text-align:justify;}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#abc").hide();
            $(".click").click(function(){
                    $("#abc").slideToggle('slow');
                });
        });
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="a">
        <p>        
            <div id="abc">
            </div>
            <h1>Welcome to ABC</h1>
            <span>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy.
            </span>
        </p>       
        <p class="click">Click ME</p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```